# How to configure custom scale in Leaflet?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wms, leaflet

I have a custom WMS tileset generated using ESRI ArcGIS Server.

I have successfully configured an OpenLayers page to display this basemap.  The code is as follows:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    projection : "EPSG:3857",
    resolutions : [ 132.29193125052919, 92.604351875370426, 67.733468800270941, 33.866734400135471, 16.933367200067735, 8.4666836000338677, 4.2333418000169338, 2.1166709000084669, 1.0583354500042335, 0.52916772500211673, 0.26458386250105836 ],
    maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(-8352920.48698, 4887220.912586, -8082558.309632, 5067712.988343)
});

var basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("basic_wm", "http://myhostname/geowebcache/service/wms/", {
    layers : 'basic_wm',
    format : 'image/jpeg'
    }, {
    tileOrigin : new OpenLayers.LonLat(-20037700, 30241100)
});
map.addLayer(basemap);
```

I am trying to reproduce the equivalent in Leaflet, but have so far been unsuccessful.  I see that I can override the scale function and set a max zoom, but I am not certain how to override the scale function.  I'm also wondering if I shouldn't be able to provide my DPI, tile origin, max extent, etc?

Here is what I have so far in Leaflet:

```
var map = new L.Map('map', {
     center: new L.LatLng(40.693726386087945, -73.9856945509795),
     zoom: 1
});

var basemap = new L.TileLayer.WMS("http://myhostname/geowebcache/service/wms/", 
    {
        layers: 'basic_wm',
        attribution: "Copyright 2012 The City of New York",
        maxZoom: 10
});
map.addLayer(basemap);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i see, there is no resolution, tile origin, max extent definition in mapOptions. i think they want to create an easy library for web mapping world. They already state that Leaflet is lightweight open-source JavaScript library....

I think it would be useful if you write needs [here](http://leaflet.uservoice.com/forums/150880-ideas-and-suggestions-for-leaflet). - Ideas and Suggestions for Leaflet...

you should be content with this method now:

[image: leaflet]

i hope it helps you...